# Instance for X448 in Bouncy Castle gives error

Tags: android, kotlin, encryption, bouncycastle

I am trying to generate Key pairs with Bouncy Castle and use the following Bouncy implementation and code:

```
implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.70'
```

According to:
https://javadoc.io/static/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.70/org/bouncycastle/math/ec/rfc7748/X448.html

I create the following keyPair generator:

```
   val keyPairGenerator =
        KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME)
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(XDHParameterSpec(XDHParameterSpec.X448))
    val keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()

    val publicKey = byteArrayToHex(keyPair.public.encoded)
    val privateKey = keyPair.private.encoded
```

But then I get the following error:

```
no such algorithm: EC for provider BC
```

I Tried diffrent providers but to no avail.

Am I missing something?

--

Removed after suggested to open a new Question

Comment: Changing an already answered question so that it goes beyond the scope of the old question is not how SO works. The old question was about generating an X448 key pair. Now it is about obtaining a shared secret and deriving a key from it. Please post a new question for this (if you can't find an answer to SO). Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is most likely caused by an older BC version being installed. This must first be removed with `Security.removeProvider("BC")`.
Then the current BC version must be added with `Security.addProvider(BouncyCastleProvider())`. Only then the instantiation of `KeyPairGenerator` may be performed.

Furthermore, when instantiating `KeyPairGenerator`, `XDHParameterSpec.X448` must be specified as first parameter (`"EC"` would generate a key pair for the EC curve *prime239v1*). The line `keyPairGenerator.initialize(...)` can be removed (it is redundant).

The following implementation works on my machine:

```kotlin
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.spec.XDHParameterSpec
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator

...

Security.removeProvider("BC")
Security.addProvider(BouncyCastleProvider())
val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(XDHParameterSpec.X448, BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME) 
val keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()
val privateKey = keyPair.private
val publicKey = keyPair.public
println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(privateKey.encoded)) // e.g. MIGBAgEBMAUGAytlbwQ6BDiMQCdpnzxOu7SN4Sgft8nsDLmbWLxWd7aDz4g3ht54NEuX2PyaGDK1mVJuTQ+v2bM9Sm9xyBN44YE5AHT/KcCEEdk/je/GU/6kg+vt8okKJAuLspjaHU1aK2KGXOKPS9GQXAHKjf/rBKj9b2IQnyesXMqU
println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKey.encoded))  // e.g. MEIwBQYDK2VvAzkAdP8pwIQR2T+N78ZT/qSD6+3yiQokC4uymNodTVorYoZc4o9L0ZBcAcqN/+sEqP1vYhCfJ6xcypQ=
```

`privateKey.encoded` returns the DER encoded private key in PKCS#8 format (incl. public key), `publicKey.encoded` returns the DER encoded key in X.509/SPKI format.

---

Alternatively, the X448 key pair can be generated as follows:

```kotlin
import java.security.SecureRandom
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.X448PrivateKeyParameters

...

val secureRandom = SecureRandom()
val privateKeyParams = X448PrivateKeyParameters(secureRandom)
val publicKeyParams = privateKeyParams.generatePublicKey()
println(Hex.toHexString(privateKeyParams.encoded))  // e.g. 0x7472d12245a698ac9a52be9bc9ea0c90aacb598f084f16a18ea917d56fa5411005a18e844a4aa4508272ad593ac8c1be53284d908d0fc4c6
println(Hex.toHexString(publicKeyParams.encoded))   // e.g. 0x9d49073bd1c0149b41cf66bd389ae743dca3bb59dc1988903c32b840fb68f8d67ccb3c56be4bc65687f11b1fc5f273d7cea329427d83a829
```

`privateKeyParams.encoded` returns the *raw* private key (56 bytes), `publicKeyParams.encoded` returns the *raw* public key (56 bytes).

Comment: thank you for your message. I Updated the topic. Is this the right implementation? I Dont get any error at the moment.

Comment: @Riccoh - A necessary criterion for correctness is that both shared secrets and derived keys are identical. In your code, only one shared secret/key is determined, so determine the respective other and compare. For further questions, please post a *new* question. Thx.